# Angular unsavedChanges plugin gives the alert twice with UI router?

Tags: angularjs

I have using the Angular unsavedChanges Plugin to find the dirty forms and alert the user when he leave the page and state. Plugin working fine but is gives the alert twice. I have changed the UI router config but still the issue not fixed

```
 angular
     .module('app', ['unsavedChanges', 'ui.router'])

 .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', 'unsavedWarningsConfigProvider',

     function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, unsavedWarningsConfigProvider) {

         $stateProvider
             .state('admin', {
                 url: '/dashboard',
                 abstract: true,
                 templateUrl: "app/app.html"
             })
             .state('admin.dashboard', {
                 url: '/home',
                 templateUrl: 'app/dashboard/dashboard.html',
                 controller: 'DashboardCtrl'
             })


         unsavedWarningsConfigProvider.useTranslateService = false;
     }
 ]);
```

Comment: This isn't helpful. Please share some code and the steps what you have tried.

Comment: added the config file